# I can't seem to integrate youtrack and github

Tags: github, issue-tracking, youtrack

Actually it seems pretty straightforward.

Here is the things I have done:

- Already have a project on Github
- Create a project on Youtrack
- Create "MD-Committers" group on Youtrack, give admin privileges on all projects.
- Add myself to the group.
- Create post-commit service hook for Youtrack with following options

.

```
url: http://myusername.myjetbrains.com/youtrack  
committers: MB-Committers  
username: root  
password: ******
active: True
```

with these settings, I `Test Hook` button says `Payload sent successfully` which means, I presume, I have set it correctly.

Then,

- Create an issue: `MD-2 integration test`
- Commit and push to `dev` branch with comment: `#MD-2 Fixed integration-test`

At this point, I should be able to see the issue status set to `Fixed` and see the commit in the history. However, **no status updates, no commits in the history**.

My-email address on Youtrack and Github are the same, the only thing different is that, in commits, I use my full name rather than my nickname.

Here is the `git log` results:

```
commit 3e91ec7021b2a87a7e4b1b79e0f53e67707e8bf4
Author: Umur Kontacı <fastreload@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 9 21:10:04 2012 +0300

    #MB-2 Fixed integration-test

commit 48686795be37aa69ca2dd7b2cd176b57945dc229
Author: Umur Kontacı <fastreload@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 9 21:05:14 2012 +0300

    #MB-2 fixed integration-test

commit 8faa55c0589e3d0f91a9988fa5aa60126651ba69
Author: Umur Kontacı <fastreload@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 9 21:04:11 2012 +0300

    #MB-2 finished integration-test

commit 4b41acfd17fbeba6b220adaef7b0dd113130a037
Author: Umur Kontacı <fastreload@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 9 20:55:13 2012 +0300

    [Finished MB-2] integration-test
```

None of the commits has made to `Youtrack`.

What the heck I am missing here?

Answer (score 3):

YouTrack parses GitHub comments as following form `[some comment text] #issueID <command_1> [command_2] ...[command_n]` as [this link](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/GitHub+Integration) mentioned.

The rule of thumb is that, any comments should be placed **before** `#issueID` and acknowledgeable YouTrack commands should be placed **after** the `#issueID`.

So, `integration-test` may not be properly acknowledged in YouTrack, because `integration-test` is just handled as unknown YouTrack command.

**Some comment #MD-2 Fixed** should work, or **#MD-2 Fixed tag integration-test** may change your issue to Fixed status and `integration-test` tagging.

Example commands can be found at http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Command+Grammar

- Note 1: recommend you to see the walkthrough video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iK1J_fWhns
- Note 2: You may mistype `MB-Committers` in your post. probably `MD`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your JetBrains account login instead of root.